# Mocha Chai Expect. How can i verify that A class is exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

As the title mentioned. I would like to ask that how could i write the test code for this scenario?

Example... i have a class look like this.

```
let ABC = function()
{
    this.title="sample"
};
```

Question is how do i use chai expect to check for the existences of ABC class?

Does expect chai do something like this?
Expect(ABC).to.be.a.class

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you had this answered yet but I had the same question and I just found out

- so after requiring chai and the expect API
- and after requiring the file where your class resides and setting up your test
- you can ensure that:

  - 1. it is a function with `.to.be.a('function');`
  - 2. check that it is an instance of your class with
       `expect(className).to.be.an.instance.of(ClassName);`

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const Card = require('../src/Card');

describe('Card', function () {
    it.skip('should be a function', function () {
        const card = new Card();
        expect(Card).to.be.a('function');
    });

    it.skip('should be an instance of Card', function () {
        const card = new Card();
        expect(card).to.be.an.instanceof(Card);
    })
})
```